# Override block within included template in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, block, overriding

Currently using Symfony2 and Twig, I'm trying to override block within an included template. Let me explain :

```
{# base.html.twig #}
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
<!--Some html Code -->
{% block javascripts %}
<!--Some scripts included like jQuery-->
{% endblock javascripts %}
```

In a other file:

```
{# page.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
{% include 'form.html.twig' %}
{% endblock content %}
```

And finally:

```
{# form.html.twig #}
<form method="post" action="something">
</form>
{# I am trying somehow to override the "javascripts" block here,
  unfortunately I didn't figured out how to to that
#}
{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
<!--Some JS here-->
{% endblock javascripts %}
```

Is there a way to do what I want ?

Answer (score 4):

What you need here is multiple inheritance. But just like php, twig does not have multiple inheritance. And just like php has traits, twig has a palliative for this called [use](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/use.html). Remember that twig is compiled to php. I think a block that is used in a `use` statement ends up compiled in a trait.

First, create your a "trait" with the blocks you want to reuse in different places:

```
{% block my_form %}
    <form method="post" action="something">
    </form>
{% endblock %}

{% block form_specific_javascript %}
    <!--Some JS here-->
{% endblock}
```

Then, in your page template, call the "trait", and reuse the blocks:

```
{# page.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    {% use 'form.html.twig' %}
    {{ block('my_form') }}
{% endblock content %}

{# override the javascript block #}
{% block javascripts %}
    {{parent()}}
    {{block('form_specific_javascript')}}
{% endblock %}
```

So as you see, you can't do it all from the form template, you have to do some
wiring in your page template. Still, calling a block is better than copy / pasting
its contents, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

Since i was looking for the same answer and actually found the solution.

It lies within TWIG with the **embed** tag.

Available in twig version 1.8, embed tag allows us to "include" a template, which has its own defined blocks who can then be overriden.

More information here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html

Answer (score 0):

You could just simply include `form.html.twig` within the `javascripts` block

**base.html.twig**

```
    {% block content %}
        <!--Some html Code -->
    {% endblock content %}

    {% block javascripts %}
        <!--Some scripts included like jQuery-->
    {% endblock javascripts %}
```

**page.html.twig**

```
    {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

    {% block javascripts %}
        {{ parent() }}
        {% include 'form.html.twig' %}
    {% endblock javascripts %}
```

**form.html.twig**

```
    <!--Some JS here-->
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It's not really what I want, since the javascript block is loaded at the nearly end of my page, and my form need to be in a specific part of the page. But I imagine some cases where this trick can be used, so thanks :)

Comment: I think you should delete your answer.

Comment: @greg0ire Explain why and I might consider doing so if it's misleading. Although the answer doesn't address the author's issue (and to be honest, I'm not certain I understand the question), it maybe useful to others, which Alex agrees might be the case.

Comment: Simply because it is off topic. That is a good reason to delete it. I was considering adding a bounty to this question and I don't like to do so if there already are wrong answers. Sorry if it is a bit harsh. BTW, I edited the question so that you can understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. I was looking for solution, but I didn't find any. Unfortunately `include`, `embed` and `use` does not solve this problem. But I figured two possible workarounds.

#### Option 1 (simpler, but needs more code)

Separate form into two files `_form.html.twig` and `_form_js.html.twig` and import them in the appropriate blocks.

#### Option 2

Invert hierarchy of templates. Extend `form` directly from `base`.

```twig
# form.html.twig
{% extends 'layouts/base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    {{ block('page_header') }}

    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script>
    # ...
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

And then extend `form` in other templates like `new` and `edit`.

```twig
# new.twig.html

{% extends 'form.html.twig' %}

{% block page_header %}

    # custom content here

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your own files, this is the approach I used and it worked for me:

```
{# base.html.twig #}

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

<!--Some html Code -->

{% block javascripts %}
<script>console.log('1st print')</script>
{% endblock %}
```

In other file:

```
{# page.html.twig #}

{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Welcome to page.html.twig.</h1>
<p>Here is a form for you to complete:</p>
{{ block("content", "form.html.twig") }}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}

<script>console.log('2nd print')</script>

{{ block("formjavascripts", "form.html.twig") }}
{% endblock %}
```

And finally:

```
{# form.html.twig #}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action="something">
</form>
{% endblock %}

{% block formjavascripts %}
<script>console.log('3rd print')</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Please notice the use of block function, you can find more info here https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/block.html

Also notice I used "formjavascripts" you could have used "javascripts" as well because that is the block name being retrieved from forms.html.twig file.

Note: You could try using Block function again in forms.html.twig and see if you can do a **4th print** and call a 4th twig file! (Not sure if this last thing will work though :P)